Exe que crea una carpeta que diga que existe lo que está dentro
Hola tengo problema con un código. Lo que quiero hacer es crear un exe que crea una carpeta dentro del exe y que diga que existe lo que está dentro.
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import shutil

archivo_txt_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), carpeta), "archivo.txt")

if os.path.exists(archivo_txt_path):
    #Mostrar que el archivo existe y su contenido
    with open(archivo_txt_path, "r") as f:
        messagebox.showinfo("Contenido del archivo", f.read())
        
else:
    #Crear La carpeta
    os.makedirs (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), carpeta))
    
    #Crear un archivo.txt y Luego moverlo
    with open("archivo.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("¡Hola! Este es un nuevo archivo.")
        
    # Mover el archivo.txt a la carpeta ###
    shutil.move("archivo.txt", os.path.join(os.path
join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), carpeta), "archivo.txt"))


Hola, mencionas que creas "un exe", dado que Python no es un lenguaje compilado y no genera ejecutables supongo que estás usando un freezer como Pyinstaller o un compilador source-to-source a otro lenguaje como C o Rust (Nuitka, PyOxidizer, etc) ¿Cuál es el caso? ¿Con qué comando/opciones? ¿Qué tipo de exe? Por ejemplo pyinstaller tienes los modos one-file y one-directory. Por otro lado, con "dentro del exe" ¿te refieres a dentro del propio archivo ejecutable o en el mismo directorio que el ejecutable?

La causa más segura de que no te genere un error es que simplemente está volviendo a crear el archivo. Agrega un print de depuración u otro message-box en el bloque del if y lo podrás comprobar. Por ejemplo, PyInstaller en el modo one-file descomprime el contenido del ejecutable (intérprete, scripts, archivos de datos, etc) en una carpeta temporal cada vez que lo "ejecutas" y es desde ese directorio desde donde se ejecuta todo.

Hola sip estoy usado Pyinstaller oculte la terminal y puse que que se guardara todo un exe como dije bueno cuando creo la carpeta si se guarda en el exe y el archivo.txt pero cuando lo vuelvo activarlo se crea otra ves el archivo.txt pero no se muestra la información como no existiera la carpeta con el archivo no se que estoy haciendo mal
